# jScrollPane: Margin issue

Tags: jquery, css, jscrollpane

Strugglig a bit with what seems to be a margin issue with jScrollPane. Tried setting margin: 0 pretty much on every element that's inside the jsp and on the actual jsp elements. I'm attaching a picture to show you the issue. The problem is the small black stripe between the content and the actual scrollbar.

[image: jsp left margin issue]

**CSS for classes inside JSP**

```
width: 100%;
min-height: 60px;
max-height: 300px;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
```

**CSS for JSP**

```
.jspContainer
{
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
}

.jspPane
{
    position: absolute;
}

.jspVerticalBar
{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0px;
    width: 5px;
    height: 100%;
    background: url('../img/staffUl.png') repeat;
}

.jspHorizontalBar
{
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 16px;
    background: red;
}

.jspVerticalBar *,
.jspHorizontalBar *
{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.jspCap
{
    display: none;
}

.jspHorizontalBar .jspCap
{
    float: left;
}

.jspTrack
{
    background: transparent;
    position: relative;
}

.jspDrag
{
    background: #2a2a2a;
    position: relative;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.jspHorizontalBar .jspTrack,
.jspHorizontalBar .jspDrag
{
    float: left;
    height: 100%;
}

.jspArrow
{
    background: #50506d;
    text-indent: -20000px;
    display: block;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.jspArrow.jspDisabled
{
    cursor: default;
    background: #80808d;
}

.jspVerticalBar .jspArrow
{
    height: 16px;
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

KG Christensen,

Literally just had the same problem as you. Took some digging around until I figured out that this is actually a "feature" of jScrollPane. The solution is to the set the config parameter 'verticalGutter' to 0. It is 4px by default.

```
$(paneElement).jScrollPane({
    verticalGutter: 0
});
```

Should do the trick!

Comment: Holy cow, that did it! Had given up on this and used some very ugly CSS instead, but now it can finally look as intended. Thank you so much :)

Comment: @KG no problem! I've been getting used to jScrollPane--it works wonders if you figure out how to use it.

Comment: Bravo :) ... its days like these that are saved by stackOverflow and its members ! +1 !