# jscrollPane Margin issue

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins, jscrollpane, jquery-jscrollpane

I am using jScrollPane plugin along with jquery Portlets. the issue that i am facing is the empty space that is inserted after I add jScrollPane plugin to my Portlet's. I have tried setting 'jspPane' margin to 0 and many other things,but nothing worked so far.
I am attaching images with and without jScrollPane to give you more clear idea.

[image]
1)With jScrollPane
[image]
2)Without jScrollPAne

any kind of help will be greatly apreciated.Thank you in advance

Comment: Use firebug or chrome's inspector to see which css rule is doing the  margins on the table or padding on the parent.

Comment: Looks like an stylesheet issue to me.

Comment: @321X ya i agree but i am not able to figure out which css property is causing this...I tried modifying css properties dynamically using firebug but still there is a empty space on the left side of content.

Comment: @Pranjali do you have an live example? Otherwise put in online in jsfiddle.net so we can help

Comment: answer is in another post:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6766382/jscrollpane-margin-issue